# Right approach to helper service (ajax) in Angular js (not dependant on scope)

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I have an angular SPA with several modules, services, factories and controllers. I have written a helper service and put it in a common folder minifed js file that all my html pages reference. They contain common bits of data obtained by an AJAX call to a database. It has to run first because the rest of the app depends on values from this helper service. The issue is that the service returns out before the promise has been returned successful, so the helper service is always empty. I do not know what the best approach is to write a helper ajax call and have all files within an angular app reference values returned by it (so everything has to wait before the promise comes back and populates the helper service). I cannot put it in the scope at the top of the main controller, because factories and services cannot reference scope variables is that right? At least I dont understand how if so.

Have searched around and found lots of ways to reference a common service from multiple controllers, but little assistance on how to access that information if the data is a result of an ajax call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not the kind of question that can be answered without seeing the code that you have attempted.  The approach you are describing is the correct approach to take, but the reason that your service isn't working is probably related to the way you are handling your `.then` callbacks from `$http`.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that the service returns out before the promise has been returned successful, so the helper service is always empty.

Try using `resolve`:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Example syntax:

```
let routerConfig = ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: "LoginCtrl"
    })
    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
      controller: "HomeCtrl",
      controllerAs: "home",
      resolve: {
        entries: function($rootScope, database) {
          return database.getEntries($rootScope.user.uid);
        }
      }
    })
}
```

There was no point displaying `HomeCtrl` so I ensured entries from database get resolved before loading... I think you can use similar technique in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a central service that other pieces of the application depend on, you can use two approaches.

Approach one would be to give the top level controller access to the data and then pass it down to all other components.

The other approach would be giving each individual component/controller direct access to the data.

Either way the code would be kind of similar. There's plenty of ways to do it but the simplest solution I use is just taking advantage of object reference:

***Factory:***

```
//you can use factory or service doesn't matter.
.factory('dataFactory', function(){
  var store = {
    data: null
  };

  //Return the entire store object
  function subscribe() {
    return store;
  };

  function fetchData() {
    $http.get('someUrl.com')
      .then(function(res) {
        //Set data to a property on the store.
        store.data = res.data;
      });
  }

  return {
    subscribe: subscribe,
    fetchData: fetchData
  };

}
```

***Controller:***

```
.controller('someController', function(dataFactory) {
  //Essentially copying over the store object in the factory by reference
  this.store = dataFactory.subscribe(); 
  //call the ajax
  dataFactory.fetchData();
}
```

***Template:***

```
<div ng-controller="someController as ctrl">
  {{ctrl.store.data}}
</div>
```

**Pros**

- Any controller in the application can get access to the store in the factory
- Since they are referencing the same object, you don't need to do any crazy event emitters or anything to notify all the controllers if the data gets updated in the factory.
- You are also caching the data in the factory. If any controllers get destroyed and re-created they can just subscribe again. The data doesn't disappear.

***Cons***

- It's bound by object reference, so any changes made to the store object anywhere in the application will change the object *everywhere*. This can be good or bad depending on what you want to happen in your application.

If you are working on a large application this can get messy, especially if you're not the only one working on it. However if this is what your application requires and you need a more robust option, i suggest checking out state management tools such as redux.

Checkout this [codepen](https://codepen.io/matthsiung/pen/EyXvxq) I made which implements a very simple version of redux.